# Is there any way to convert a sql query into hql query with REGEXP

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

Is there any way to convert the SQL query with `REGEXP` to HQL query fro this example.

```
SELECT * FROM product m WHERE id = 19 and m.name REGEXP ('DEf|abc');

SELECT * FROM product m WHERE id = 19 and m.name REGEXP ('DEf|abc');
```

where name is column having json values

I expect the output will display the results but i am getting an error

> UNEXPECTED TOKEN REGEXP.

Comment: Hi, you can create your own dialect and register the function.

Comment: I understand that this question is not duplicated, because this question could be answered registering a function on hibernate Dialect to map REGEXP from MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

HQL does not have regular expressions.

but for this  you could use  a like  or

```
    SELECT * FROM product m 
    WHERE id = 19 
    and ( m.name like '%Def%' or m.name like '%abc%' );
```